# MS-Access conditional format date in tabular forms row by row

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, conditional-statements

I have created a database to store genealogical records. I have created a tabular form to display records which include a date text box, however I am struggling to display the date text boxes with the formatting different on each row. The different formats I require are "dd/mm/yyyy" where a full date is known, "yyyy" where the year only is known, and the text box to be left blank if the date is unknown. The table the form is aligned to has a field to indicate whether the date is a full date, year only, or no date - field values "fd", "yo" and "nd" so easy to test the format required for each row.
I cannot see how this is possible using the Conditional Format option.
I am happy to use VBA but have struggled with this. I am new to Access and new to VBA but have a technical background (coding in C++ and Java) and VBA currently looks alien to me - but willing to get into it.
Any pointers please will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a continuous form since the format is applied at the control. Perhaps it could be easier to format at source (query) using an inline-if `IIF(condition, True, False)` or `Switch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always store dates as DateTime as it can be stored as *Null* for unknown.

Then, have a Boolean field, YearOnly, to mark values where only the year is known; store the year with any date of the year, like 2020-01-01.

Now, use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [Date], 
    YearOnly, 
    Format([Date],"yyyy" & IIf(Not [YearOnly],"-mm-dd")) AS DisplayDate
FROM 
    YourTable;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] Thank you Kostas K and Gustav, I have implemented the query you suggest, which took me a while to figure out, but I have it now working in my tabular form. My problem was I was trying to achieve this using VBA on loading the form. VBA wise I am a complete novice.
Thanks Bob H